# embedded polymorphic association model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have these models:

model 1:

```
module Ems  
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images, :as => :imageable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images 
  end
end
```

model 2:

```
module Ems
  class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  end
end
```

view:

```
= form_for @article do |f|
  %div
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title
  %div
    - f.fields_for :images do |builder| 
      = builder.label :title
      = builder.text_field :title
```

I don't get any errors however I also dont get the form fields for the embedded image form. All I get is an empty DIV.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: not sure but you can try after replacing - with = at line
`  - f.fields_for :images do |builder| `

Comment: Doh, was getting a little late. Do you want to put the comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try after replacing - with = at where you are calling fields_for

```
 = f.fields_for :images do |builder|
```

The fields_for returns form HTML, so you need to render it on UI.